# Normal Operator $\| T^2\| = \|T\|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a complex inner product space X, and an operator $T: X \rightarrow X$ is normal i.e. $T^*T=TT^*$ 
How can we show $\| T^2\| = \|T\|^2$?

By the definition of operator norm, it follows that ||T|| = sup $\frac{||Tx||}{||x||}$ and ||T$^2$|| = sup $\frac{||T^2x||}{||x||}$. Then I can express the numerator as a form of inner product. But I still am not able to make these two equal. Any good ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $T$ is normal, then $\|Tx\|^2=\left<Tx,Tx\right>=\left<x,T^*Tx\right>
=\left<x,TT^*x\right>=\|T^*x\|^2$, so $\|Tx\|=\|T^*x\|$ (and therefore
$\|T\|=\|T^*\|$).
Then (replacing $x$ by $Tx$)
$\|T^2x\|=\|T^*Tx\|$ so that $\|T^2\|=\|T^*T\|$. But also
$\|Tx\|^2=\left<x,T^*Tx\right>\le\|T^*T\|\|x\|^2$ so that $\|T\|^2\le\|T^*T\|
=\|T^2\|$. But $\|T^2\|\le\|T\|^2$. We conclude that $\|T^2\|=\|T\|^2$
whenever $T$ is normal.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, how can we get (i) ||Tx|| = ||T*x|| implies that ||T|| = ||T*||?

Comment: (ii) why can we have <x, T$^*$Tx>   $\leq$  ||T$^*$T|| ||x||$^2$?

Comment: By the definition: $\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|$. @Eric

Comment: @eric $|\left<x,Ax\right>|\le\|x\|\|Ax\|\le\|A\|\|x\|^2$.